# Neural Network Input 0 of layer "sequential_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4), found shape=(None, 2)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I am working with some data to make a trainable model suing Neural Network.
This is the code I am working on:

```
import os, time, random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from google.colab import files

df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Deep Learning Final Project/ObjectDetection/train_solution_bounding_boxes (1).csv')
df.rename(columns={'image':'image_id'}, inplace=True)
df.head(13)

X = df.iloc[:,:2].values
y = df.iloc[:,3:10].values
print(X.shape, y.shape)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
model = StandardScaler()
X = model.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
y = ohe.fit_transform(y).toarray()
y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.1)

# Building nural network model 
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Here below I have a problem with running this section 

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=64)
```

It gives me this error

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4), found shape=(None, 2)`

Please any one can help we solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first layer of the network `model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))` expects an input of dimension 4, (as specified by `input_dim=4`).

That's why the error says `Input 0 of layer "sequential_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4)`. It means, the *initial layer* (`Input 0`) of the Sequential model is expecting an array of length=4.

Now, the input is given by `X = df.iloc[:,:2].values`, *i.e* only two columns are passed as input. Thus, the error says `found shape=(None, 2)`.
Check the value of `X.shape`. Its 2nd index would be 2.

This is the mismatach. Fix `model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))` as the **input_dim=2**. It will work.

Moreover, after you fix this, check for the first dimension. `None` should not work. Fix that as well.